# Insert spaces into a string using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Insert spaces into a string using Ruby

Ex: I have `"LoremIpsumDolorSitAmet"`, I want to get this `"Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"`

Comment: What if there are single uppercase characters like `"ThisIsAString"`?

Comment: In my task of such options do not exist, but i assume that the character should be split well as the rest words like "This Is A String".

Comment: -1 for anonymous close-voters. There is nothing whatsoever wrong with this question.

Comment: @AlexD It is not a question. It just describes that the OP wants to do something. Furthermore, it is not even clear what the OP wants to do. The OP does not describe what the rules are to insert spaces.

Comment: -1 for close-voters.  The question was clear enough for google to find it, and for an answer to be offered.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming Ruby 1.9:

```
result = subject.split(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/)
```

This splits between a lowercase and an uppercase ASCII letter.

To insert spaces instead:

```
result = subject.gsub(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/, ' ')
```

See here:

```
irb(main):001:0> "LoremIpsumDolorSitAmet".gsub(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/, ' ')
=> "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet"
```

If there can be single uppercase letters, you'd need to change your regex a bit:

```
irb(main):003:0* "ThisIsAString".gsub(/(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[A-Z])/, ' ')
=> "This Is A String"
```